# What does ཕལ་པོ་ཆེ། (translated to the Flower Ornament Sutra) really mean?

Tags: tibetan-buddhism, texts, translation

I am not versed in Tibetan language but wanted to know what the literal meaning of ཕལ་པོ་ཆེ། is, which is translated into either of [these](http://www.thlib.org/encyclopedias/literary/canons/kt/catalog.php#cat=d/k-1-3-1)

- The Sūtra of the Buddhas' Vastness
- The Flower Ornament Sūtra

Those are very different words, so I'm wondering what the essence of the etymology or whatever is. Wondering if one could layout the literal components of the word and how they could possibly be translated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ཕལ་པོ་ཆེ་ is *mdo phal po che* (Dopel Poché in Standard Tibetan) [according to the Rigpa](https://www.rigpawiki.org/index.php?title=%E0%BD%95%E0%BD%A3%E0%BC%8B%E0%BD%94%E0%BD%BC%E0%BC%8B%E0%BD%86%E0%BD%BA%E0%BC%8B)

- mdo means "sutra"
- phal by itself means "ordinary (person)"
- po is a masculine agentive
- che means "great", "greatest"

One of the English translations [on this site](http://rywiki.tsadra.org/index.php/phal_po_che) is "great host".